# finding the roots of polynomial of degree 3

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Please hint me. How can I factor this polynomial?
I want to find the roots of $x^3+(1-2n)x^2-(1+4n)x+8n^2-10n-1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't have any nontrivial factors that are polynomials in $n$ and $x$.  You can use the [standard formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicFormula.html) for solving a cubic, but the result won't be pretty.

Comment: It's not that bad. Using Lagrange resolvents, then, $$x = \frac{1}{3}\big(2n-1+y_1^{1/3}+y_2^{1/3}\big)$$ where $y_i$ are the roots of the quadratic, $$y^2 - 8 (2 + 33 n - 21 n^2 + 2 n^3) y + 64 (1 + n)^6 =0$$

Comment: thanks,may you give me more explain? Please.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is to fix a given $n\ge 1$, and then factor the polynomial $f_n(x)$. For $n=0,1,2,3,4$ this works as follows:
\begin{align*}
f_0(x) & = (x + 1)^2(x - 1), \\
f_1(x) & =(x + 1)^2(x - 3), \\
f_2(x) & = (x^2 - 2x - 11)(x - 1), \\
f_3(x) & = x^3 - 5x^2 - 13x + 41, \\
f_4(x) & = (x^2 - 4x - 29)(x - 3).
\end{align*}

Comment: Any given linear factor $x - r$ occurs for at most two values of $n$.  $f(x,n)=0$ is an elliptic curve, by the way.  Its Weierstrass normal form is $y^3 - 256 y - 1024 + t^2$.